Why did Hannibal cross the alps and NOT just cross the Mediterranean?
In crossing the Alps Hannibal lost half his men to mountains, and Carthage still had a huge navy back then, so it would be more reasonable to directly cross the Mediterranean into Italy and avoid the Alps, because even if there was more Roman resistance, Hannibal, a strategic genius that attacked Rome with 30000 men, probably wouldn't have suffered THAT much. Also, the Carthaginians were more experienced particularly in naval warfare, so even if the Romans took their fleet and fought Hannibal, Hannibal would have won, also they could directly attack Rome that way.

Where have you looked already? Please note that we require some evidence of prior research. For example, have you looked at How Hannibal Crossed the Alps - does it answer your question? If not, please to explain why so that we can help you. Thank you!

The Wikipedia article on the crossing spells out the reasons quite well imho. Very condensed: To make up for the (especially economic) loss of Siciliy, the Barcas faction set out to occupy Ibera. There, they ran into local powers that called to Rome for help. That gave the Barcas the conflict with Rome they were actually looking for, indirectly at first. Before Hannibal crossed the alps, he already marched all the way to the alps. It would have been absurd to go all the way back and attack over sea.

Also, I'm sooo temped to link a Weird Al song here. Because I consider getting thrown something like this question at me, with its severe dearth of spelling, grammar and so forth, a big sign of disrespect. "I'll just vomit something onto the website, let those idiots figure out what I, like, meant, prububly." And no, not everybody and their grandma is dyslexic.See also this entry in the help center. Sorry, I don't want to step on anybody's toes, but things like this really irk me.

Actually, I kinda liked this question. Sure its simple, but there are multiple answers.

Question is founded on a set of unsupported (and probably unsupportable) assertions.

Where was Hannibal's army?

Because Rome had "complete mastery of the seas" according to "The Influence of Sea-power on the History of the Roman Republic." Dissertation by Frederick William Clark for the University of Chicago (1915). p. 43.... and many other sources.
During the First Punic War (264-241 BC) Carthage and Rome had fought a series of sea battles, but ultimately Rome prevailed which resulted in Carthage losing Sicily. By the time of the Second Punic War (218-201 BC) Rome had accomplished nearly complete mastery of the seas vis-a-vis Carthage and this was reinforced by Rome's capture of Malta (218 BC). On the other hand, Carthage had been achieving military success on the land and controlled most of Spain by the time Hannibal made his invasion. Hannibal's victory at the Siege of Saguntum (219 BC) gave him a strong post to supply him for an invasion of Italy and encouraged him to make the attempt.

@njuffa Recall that in Classical times ships strongly preferred to sail during the day and to put into shore at night. Accordingly, sea travel tended to follow coasts and avoided long sea crossings. So the answer could have more precisely said that Rome had mastery of the seas around Italy and Sicily. (They could extend their dominance further afield at considerable cost, but did not routinely patrol the African or Iberian coasts.)

@njuffa - The chances of getting noticed and intercepted making a 13KM trip across the Straights of Gibraltar in the middle of their own territory vs the chances of getting intercepted making an 850 KM trip into Roman territory is a pretty drastic difference. Not to mention Rome was ready and looking for a naval attack, because that's how Carthage did it in the First Punic War.

@njuffa - I'll try to remember to look it up when I get back to my library, but IIRC Hanniabal's army by the time of the First Punic War was largely recruited in Hispania. WP says the original Carthaginian army brought over to Hispania by his father made the passage overland crossing at the straights, although the story sounds rather legendary.
